# Create view of Student ID,firstname,coursename

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-view

Create a view named course student details which has the following attributes. Student id, first name, and course name which they have registered.

It contains 3 tables

1. Course:
   Courseid,
   Coursename,
   Duration,
   Fees
2. Registration:
   Courseid,
   Studid,
   Doj
3. Student:
   Studid,
   Firstname,
   Lastname,
   Street,
   City,
   DOB

Comment: Are you trying to solve your homework here? Have you even tried something?

Comment: I tired the program but while I try to type  it in the question it shows like this.  "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: just add \``` before and after the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you want joins:

```
create view course_student_details as
select s.first_name, s.last_name, c.course_name
from students s
inner join registration r on r.stud_id = s.stud_id
inner join course c on c.course_id = r.course_id
```